# UI is not responsive when datagridview loading data in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox, backgroundworker

I have a listbox, datagridview and textbox in winforms.

Here is what I am trying to do

When the user selects an item in listbox, datagridview is loaded with some data regarding to the item selected and also there is a autocomplete textbox with a custom source which changes dynamically based on the item selected.

datasource for datagridview and autocomplete textbox is from the rdbms (MYSQL).

```
private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string item=listBox1.SelectedValue.Tostring();
    UpdateDataGridView(item);
    UpdateACTextBox(item);
}
```

Until this operation is completed, user cannot able to select another item in listbox, it takes almost 10 seconds to finish.

To resolve this, I came across some solutions like asynchronous method.

Which is the best way to resolve this problem?

Backgroundworker,
async and await,
threadpool,
multithreading.

Please suggest something if I have not researched properly.

What is the conventional way developers follow to these types of problems?

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention that I am using VS2010. Since async and await is not supported in vs2010. I think I need to drop that option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it depends where you have more experience. I usually use async/awayt and call methods that return only Data, don't call any UI properties inside those methods. After that everything is bound to the UI elements.

Comment: @Eugen Is it possible to use async/await in a method which returns datatable?
Cause I read that async/await should be used only on void methods, Task

Comment: @CSTRAIZE, where did you read that? `void` returning methods are only to be used in the case of event handlers (like `listBox1_SelectedValueChanged`), but everything else should return `Task` (or `Task<T>`).

Comment: @PauloMorgado Ya I understood. I have one more doubt, when a user clicks an item in listbox, asynchronously a job is done for 10 seconds with that item value, meanwhile when user selects another item and another item. Does it mean, the job will be done for 10 seconds+10 seconds, then UI is responsive.

Comment: Can I cancel the running async/await job when new async/await call is made?

Comment: 10 seconds is a long time in the database world.  While a background worker would probably help, you are probably doing something fundamentally slow in the UpdateDataGridView or UpdateACTextBox methods.  You didn't show us that.

Comment: @LarsTech Actually it fetches nearly 5000 records for each listbox item. I guess backgroundworker should solve my problem.  
Can I cancel the running backgroundworker job when new backgroundworker call is made?

Comment: 5,000 records shouldn't take 10 seconds to get, so you are still doing something fundamentally wrong in your Update methods.  On the other hand, you aren't doing the end user any favors by showing them 5,000 records.  Too many.

Comment: @LarsTech yes. You are right. Actually this project was done by another developer(beginner), i am trying to make it a better application.

Comment: Can I cancel the running backgroundworker job when new backgroundworker call is made?

Comment: With an `async void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged` `listBox1_SelectedValueChanged` becames fire-and-forget. You have to managem currency. If your async operation accepts a `CancellationToken` you can use one to cancel the operation.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Since async/await is not supported by default in vs2010. I am dropping that option. Please suggest any other alternative for asynchronous operation.

Comment: So, why did you tag the question `async-await`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is that the amount of data you are loading to the listView is to big. So i would suggest using a background task in combination with the VirtualMode of the listView. In virtual mode the datas are not stored inside of the listView you have to store the values outside in a list of your own. If needed the listView will call a event to ask you for the value. Simply return a dummy or use old values if the data is not available. This will let the listview simply blanke or showing the old values. After the values are finished copied in a list simply exchange the pointer (variable) of the  list with a atomic operation. From that point on the new datas are used to update the list and not the old one. Call update function to load the new valuses.  This methode allowes it although to update the data in the background and update it from time to time. Only drawback you need to store the values of your list twice. Inside of the old shown buffer and inside of the new currently updated one. I hope that helps.